# Can I composite primary key be used in place of an ID primary key?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I currently have a database setup where there are 5 columns set as the composite primary key which could uniquely identify a row. Should I still have an ID column to identify each row? It seems redundant, although I am not sure of what is standard.

I am using SQLAlchemy. I noticed that when I had the 5 columns as the composite primary key, the table was significantly slower inserting the data from a CSV file, as compared to if I had an ID column. It was half the speed with the column (not sure if this is relevant).

To be clear: My question is, Should I have an ID column alongside the composite primary key, even though the ID column would be redundant?

Comment: So you still had the 5 columns identified as UNIQUE, just not PRIMARY?

Comment: I have these fields only marked as primary. I am under the impression that primary keys must be unique. But I can mark them as unique as they should be. Would the columns being unique and primary make it a possible substitute for not having an ID column?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should always have a separate rowid (either int based one-up or UUID).  Especially when you get into other aspects of mysql or database DevOps, having that ID field is a lifesaver (e.g., replication or galera clustering).  It also makes working with frameworks like django much easier.

Comment: Is it also recommended for it to be a primary key? What I want to do (in SQLAlchemy) is to have that ID, but not as the primary key, but have it be unique and auto_increment.

Comment: No need for it to be the primary key, but recommended (for purposes of faster querying and index-size) that you use it as **a** key.  There are a lot of finer aspects to mysql, like cluster indexing, that would be made easier if it were a primary key, but it is not necessary for things like replication or galera clustering.

Comment: Or alternatively 'no, while it can be immensely useful in some situations, it can also add unnecessary redundancy to your data set'